SQLAlchemy Case Expression In Filter
Is there a way to use the the in_ operator on a case expression.  The below is a contrived example but I am looking to do something like this.
I am able to define a hybrid_property along with an expression and that works but can I do this dynamically in a query?
# This does not work
class ReferralModel(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    referrer_id = Column(Integer)


Session.query(ReferralModel.id).filter(case((ReferralModel.referrer_id.is_(None), -20), else_=ReferralModel.referrer_id).in_([-20, 10]))

referral table



id
referrer_id




10
NULL


20
10



SELECT *
FROM referral
WHERE CASE WHEN referrer_id IS NULL THEN -20 ELSE referrer_id END IN (-20, 10)
# This works
class ReferralModel(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    referrer_id = Column(Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def referrer_id_no_nulls(self) -> int:
        return self.referrer_id if not self.referrer_id else -20
        
    @referrer_id_no_nulls.expression
    def referrer_id_no_nulls_expression(cls):
        return case((cls.referrer_id.is_(None), -20), else_=cls.referrer_id)    


Session.query(ReferralModel.id).filter(ReferralModel.referrer_id_no_nulls_expression.in_([-20, 10]))


The entire case should be wrapped. Try this:
from sqlalchemy import case, literal

Session.query(ReferralModel.id).filter(
    case(
        [(ReferralModel.referrer_id.is_(None), literal(-20))],
        else_=ReferralModel.referrer_id
    ).in_([-20, 10])
)


As of v2.0 (or v1.4 with future=True) SQLAlchemy no longer requires cases statements be wrapped in square brackets ([]).

Without a minimal reproducible example I can't actually test if this would work, but I think you're looking for a column_property with a Comparator.
This is a rough example of how it could be used, but obviously untested so may require fixing.
class CustomComparator(Comparator):

    def __init__(self, column_property, mapper):
        super().__init__(case((cls.referrer_id == None, -20), else_=cls.referrer_id))
        self.cls = mapper.class_

    def __eq__(self, value):
        return or_(
            self.cls.referrer_id == value,
            and_(self.cls.referrer_id == None and value == -20),
        )

    def __ne__(self, value):
        return and_(
            self.cls.referrer_id != value,
            or_(self.cls.referrer_id != None, value != -20),
        )

    def in_(self, values):
        return or_(
            and_(-20 in values, self.cls.referrer_id == None),
            and_(self.cls.referrer_id.in_(values)),
        )

    def not_in(self, values):
        return ~self.in_(values)

class ReferralModel(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    referrer_id = Column(Integer)

    referrer_id_no_nulls = column_property(
        case((cls.referrer_id == None, -20), else_=cls.referrer_id),
        comparator_factory=CustomComparator,
    )

